# Damping ratio and natural frequency of a second order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm supposed to find the natural frequency and damping coefficient for the system described by differential equation (y(t) output u(t) input))

$$
\frac{10 d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + \frac{0.1dy(t)}{dt} + 1000y(t) = 35u(t)
$$

I know damping ratio and natural frequency is defined as following in laplacian domain

$$
Y(s) = \frac{(s+2\gamma\omega_n)y_0}{s^2+2\gamma\omega_ns+w_n^2}
$$

where $$\gamma = \text {damping ratio}$$
$$\omega_n = \text{natural frequency}
$$

so I try to take the laplace transform of the above function and get something like

$$
10(S^2Y(S)-Sy_0) + 0.1(SY(S)-y_0)+1000Y(S) - \frac {35}{s} = 0
$$

where 
$$
y_0 = y(0^-)  
$$

(dy/dt omitted because at 0-, dy/dt = 0)

because of that 35/s term, I don't think I can put this nicely into Y(s) to get the damping ratio and natural frequency.

How is this type of problem handled?